# Liquibase Rollback with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, liquibase

Here I want to ask the community about how to use correctly the Python package: [pyliquibase](https://pypi.org/project/pyliquibase/).

Based on the doc I need to provide the path to the `liquibase.properties` file, where I need to declare all relevant properties to my liquibase migration/rollback. But for me not really obvious how should I specify the correct data in case if have my own database liquibase artifact (some_DB_liquibase.jar) with the changelog file inside that artifact.

Here is the question, how can I specify the classpath:path/to/changelog.xml (inside the .jar file) to be understandable for that library instead of unpacking the some_DB_liquibase.jar and providing it by the absolute path to the changelog file.

Here is example of my current properties file:

```
changelogFile: classpath:path/to/my/changelog-current.xml
driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://{db_host}:${db_port}/{db_name}?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;noAccessToProcedureBodies=true
username: {db_user}
password: {db_password}
defaultSchemaName: {db_name}
classpath: /absolute/path/to/connector/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar:/absolute/path/to/my/db_liquibase/artifact/{db_name}.jar
```

Here is my test code:

```
import os
import pyliquibase

root_path = os.getcwd()
liquibase_properties = f'{root_path}/path/to/liquibase.properties'
rollback_datetime = '2023-06-12T12:00:00'

def liquibase_rollback():
    liquibase = pyliquibase.Pyliquibase(liquibase_properties, logLevel='INFO')
    liquibase.rollback_to_datetime(rollback_datetime)

liquibase_rollback()
```

Log error that I have received:

```
[2023-06-16 17:22:34] INFO [liquibase.ui] ####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ## 
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ## 
##  Free schema change activity reports at        ##
##      https://hub.liquibase.com                 ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
Starting Liquibase at 17:22:34 (version 4.21.1 #9070 built at 2023-04-13 20:56+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.21.1
[2023-06-16 17:22:34] INFO [liquibase.ui] Liquibase Version: 4.21.1
Liquibase Open Source 4.21.1 by Liquibase
[2023-06-16 17:22:34] INFO [liquibase.ui] Liquibase Open Source 4.21.1 by Liquibase
[2023-06-16 17:22:35] INFO [liquibase.integration] Starting command execution.
[2023-06-16 17:22:39] INFO [liquibase.lockservice] Successfully acquired change log lock
[2023-06-16 17:22:39] INFO [liquibase.lockservice] Successfully released change log lock
[2023-06-16 17:22:40] INFO [liquibase.command] Command execution complete
[2023-06-16 17:22:40] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] ERROR: The file 'classpath:path/to/my/changelog-current.xml' was not found.
The file property cannot be configured with a fully qualified path, but must be a relative path on the property,
and any local or remote base of the path set on the search path.
liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ERROR: The file 'classpath:path/to/my/changelog-current.xml' was not found.
The file property cannot be configured with a fully qualified path, but must be a relative path on the property,
and any local or remote base of the path set on the search path.
        at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:235)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:55)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:24)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$null$2(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:383)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:203)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$3(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:358)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:203)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.execute(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:356)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: ERROR: The file 'classpath:path/to/my/changelog-current.xml' was not found.
The file property cannot be configured with a fully qualified path, but must be a relative path on the property,
and any local or remote base of the path set on the search path.
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:114)
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:15)
        at liquibase.command.core.helpers.DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.getDatabaseChangeLog(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.java:100)
        at liquibase.command.core.helpers.DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.run(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.java:77)
        at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:212)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: The solution from my side was to create a function for creating and writing the properties inside the needed file dynamically. I have used the FastAPI temple of service to create a swagger endpoint which will take that configuration as a dictionary template with needed data to make a rollback dynamically and call it afterward.